# Element Tree find output empty text

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have a problem using Element Tree to extract the text.

My format of my xml file is

```
<elecs id = 'elecs'>
    <elec id = "CLM-0001" num = "0001">
        <elec-text> blah blah blah </elec-text>
        <elec-text> blah blah blah </elec-text>
    </elec>
    <elec id = "CLM-0002" num = "0002">
         <elec-text> blah blah blah </elec-text>
         <elec-text> blah blah blah </elec-text>
    </elec>
 </elecs>
```

I want to extract out all the text inside the tag

Assume that our xml file is in the variable xml

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import lxml import etree
parser = etree.XMLParser(recover = True)
contents = open(xml).read()
tree = ET.fromstring(contents, parser = parser)
elecsN = tree.find('elecs')
for element in elecsN:
    print element.text
```

The problem is, the code above returns empty strings. I have tried my code above with other tags in my document and it works. I do not know why it returns empty string this time.

Is there anyway i can solve this problem.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you actually mean 'any way' you could use lxml.

```
>>> from io import StringIO
>>> html = StringIO('''\
... <elecs id = 'elecs'>
...     <elec id = "CLM-0001" num = "0001">
...             <elec-text> blah blah blah </elec-text>
...             <elec-text> blah blah blah </elec-text>            
...     </elec>
...     <elec id = "CLM-0002" num = "0002">    
...          <elec-text> blah blah blah </elec-text>
...          <elec-text> blah blah blah </elec-text>         
...     </elec>
... </elecs>
... '''
... )
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> doc = etree.parse(html)
>>> doc.xpath('//elecs/elec/*/text()')
[' blah blah blah ', ' blah blah blah ', ' blah blah blah ', ' blah blah blah ']
```

Comment: Forget this answer and look at the one offered by har07!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply find elements that directly contains the text by name i.e `elec-text` in this case :

```
>>> elec_texts = tree.findall('.//elec-text')  
>>> for elec_text in elec_texts:                            
...     print elec_text.text                              
...                                               
 blah blah blah                                   
 blah blah blah                                   
 blah blah blah                                   
 blah blah blah
```